# Is KMP Algorithm's jumps error-prone?

Tags: algorithm

Let's consider an example:
text = "AABCAABDCAAB",
pattern = "AABCAAB"

In this example, the pattern will match at index = 0
**AABCAAB**DCAAB
**AABCAAB**

According to the KMP algorithm, when j = pattern length, we found a match and reset j = lps[pattern length - 1] = 3, this means pattern[j] = 'C'

The algorithm made a jump:
AABCAAB**D**CAAB
_____AAB**C**AAB

without consider the cases between the jump, for example:
AABCAABDCAAB
_AABCAAB

AABCAABDCAAB
__AABCAAB
...

Is it possible to overlook some matches in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The KMP algorithm is proved to work correctly in all cases. The main idea behind it is that if you have matched the first k characters of the pattern, you know k characters of text, because they match those k characters exactly. The shift table is calculated so that the shift to be used when you have matched k characters is as far as you can safely go, given the knowledge of those k characters.

In your example you have just matched AABCAAB, so you know the text is AABCAAB. There is only one C in the pattern, which you have just matched, so you must move the pattern on far enough that the C that used to match doesn't overlap any part of the pattern at the next attempted match, which in this case gives you the next attempted match position.

(I note that the KMP algorithm is usually described and proved not as making irregular shifts of the pattern but of stepping regularly along the text to be searched and working out how many characters of the pattern have been matched so far. Because there is a proof using that view of the algorithm we know that it works in all cases).